# notifydatasetchanged not working after app close?

Tags: java, android

My code is as follows. I have a couple of classes and when someone want to update it doesn't work.what could be the problem?
I checked it a lot and the application closes = arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

```
public class CardArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Card> {


    public CardArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource,List<Card> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position,View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       Card card = getItem(position);
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item,parent,false);
        TextView textView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.ItemTextView);
        ImageView imageView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.ItemImageView);
        textView.setText(card.name);
        Glide.with(getContext()).load(card.photoURL).into(imageView);
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Main class

```
ArrayList<Card> list;
CardArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;
public void loadsCards(){
        list=new ArrayList<Card>();
         String name = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                                    String photoURL = dataSnapshot.child("photo").getValue().toString();
                                    String uid = dataSnapshot.getKey();
                                    Card card = new Card(uid,photoURL,name);
                                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "sonuc:"+card.name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                   list.add(card);
                       arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); //closes here
                                  }
```

Comment: Stacktrace please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are trying to use `RecyclerView` and populate it with your `arrayAdapter`.You are missing the statement to instruct the recycler view to use the adapter.

Try adding this and check if it works

```
recyclerView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

If you are using any other views such as `ListView` you have to set your adapter to that.

```
listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

If you are not using any views, you can't get your data populated. Please check this article for more on ArrayAdapter: 
[ArrayAdapter with ListView](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView), [ArrayAdapter with RecyclerView](https://guides.codepath.com/android/using-the-recyclerview)

Comment: I solved the problem.
 list=new ArrayList<Card>();
//adding code
arrayAdapter=new CardArrayAdapter(this.getContext(),list.size(),list);
//
thank you for helping you solve it.

Answer (score 1):

//I solved the problem. 
`list=new ArrayList<Card>();`
//adding code 
`arrayAdapter=new CardArrayAdapter(this.getContext(),list.size(),list);`